# VBA - SQL request with filter

Tags: sql, vba

I would like to do a SQL request in VBA that avoids some values.

1. First I do a request that give me the values I do not want:

   I put those values in a table `a` for example: `a = (1, 25, 3)`
2. Then I would like to do a request like:

```vb
    rst.Source = "SELECT TableNumerosClients.NOM_CLIENT ," & _
                 "FROM table.Clients WHERE NOT table.id in a ;"
```

My problem here is a, I do not know how to make the query understand that `a = (1, 25, 3)`

Thanks

Comment: What does the SQL for the first request look like?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your example object `a` is genuinely a ***table*** and not an *array* of values, there are a couple of ways to accomplish this:

**Using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:**

```sql
select c.nom_client
from clients c
where c.id not in (select a.id from a)
```

**Using a `LEFT JOIN`:**

```sql
select c.nom_client
from clients c left join a on c.id = a.id
where a.id is null
```